# Rails 4.1 ActionController::UnknownFormat error for respond_with using AngularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

Keep getting ActionController:UnknownFormat error when trying to use respond_to and respond_with in rails controller. Error on the following line in controller.

```
respond_with @surveys
```

In /app/assets/controllers/surveys_controller

```
respond_to :json

def index
  @surveys = Survey.all
  respond_with @surveys
end
```

In /config/routes.rb

```
WebInsight::Application.routes.draw do

   scope :api do
      resources :surveys, defaults: {format: 'json'}
   end

   resources :surveys
end
```

In /app/assets/views/surveys/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Your Surveys</h1>

<form>
  <input type="text" ng-model='newSurvey' placeholder="Enter a survey">
  <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>

<div ng-controller="SurveysCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="survey in surveys">
          {{ survey.theme_id }}, {{ survey.name }}, {{ survey.description }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In /app/assets/javascripts/angular/controllers/surveys_ctrl.js

```
app.controller('SurveysCtrl', ['$scope', '$resource', function($scope, $resource) {
   var Surveys = $resource('/api/surveys');
   $scope.surveys = Surveys.query();
}]);
```

Answer (score 3):

it seams that having

```
respond_to :json
```

is valid when the routes defines json as the default

```
scope :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
  resources :resources
end
```

to not allow the html in the Controller simply add the following to the method

```
def new
  @resource = Resource.new
  respond_with(@resource) do |format|
    format.html { render nothing: true, status: :unauthorized }
    format.json { render :json => @resource.as_json }
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you please add more details about the solution you provide?

Comment: hi, wanted to increase your rep by 1000%

Answer (score 2):

In `/app/assets/controllers/surveys_controller` you could change `respond_with` to `render json:` like so:

```
def index
  @surveys = Survey.all
  render json: @surveys
end
```

That worked for me using Rails 4.1.5.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with the following amendment:

In /app/assets/controllers/surveys_controller, use

```
respond_to :json, :html
```

instead of just

```
respond_to :json
```

Comment: A word of caution here:
If you put respond_to :json, :html, it means rails will continue to serve HTML output using rails, not angular. If you want AngularJS to be serving all HTML content as the front-end, while rails only handles back-end (as should be the case for 1 page apps), you should not enable `respond_to :html`. Instead, read up on AngularJS routing.
[http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating]